# Finding the norm of an operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Here is the question:

Let $X = C[0,1]$ with $\|.\|_{\max}$ norm, let $\{ \alpha_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ be real numbers, let $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n} \subset [0,1],$ and define $$ T f = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k} f(x_{k}). $$ Prove that $T$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and find its norm.

I managed to prove that $T$ is linear and bounded, where $$\|T\| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha_{k}|$$\

**My questions are: **

1-is my bound correct ?

2- How can I find the norm? I do not know if my function increasing $f$ or decreasing, I do not know how to think to find the norm, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your bound is correct. Let $X = C[0,1]$ with the $\sup$-norm and let $\{\alpha_k\}_{k = 1}^n \subset [0,1]$ as in the question. Let $f \in X$ be arbitrary with $\Vert f \Vert = 1$, then

$$  \vert Tf \vert = \vert \sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha_k f(x_k) \vert \leq \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \vert = \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert $$

and hence $$\Vert T \Vert = \sup_{f \in X, \Vert f \Vert = 1} \vert Tf \vert \leq \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert ~~.$$

In fact, this is the norm of the functional, since $\sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert$ is attained by the following function $f$. Define

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = x_k, \alpha_k \geq 0 \\
-1 & x = x_k, \alpha_k < 0 \\
0 & x \in \{0,1\} \setminus \{x_k\}_{k =1}^n
\end{cases}$$

and linear interpolation otherwise. Then this function is continuous on $[0,1]$, it has $\Vert f \Vert = 1$, and we have

$$ \vert Tf \vert = \vert \sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha_k f(x_k) \vert = \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert$$

where in the last step we use that all summands are positive. Hence $\Vert T \Vert \geq \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert$, and thus we have equality.

Comment: I did not get your point of showing $\Vert T \Vert \geq \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert$, could you explain more please?

Comment: What do you mean by "linear interpolation"?

Comment: How do you know that $ \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert \alpha_k \vert$ is attained by the function you defined? could you please explain more?

Comment: Does you function takes 2 values at 0 and 1?

Comment: @Mathstupid: Consider the definition of an operator norm. We say $||T||=\sup_{||x||=1} |T(x)|$. Hence, if you find a function with $||x||=1$ such that $|T(x)|=c||x||$=c, it must follows that the $\sup$ over all such $||x||=1$ is at least $c$. Also, linear interpolation just means connect $(0,f(0))$ to $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_1,f(x_1))$ to $(x_2,f(x_2))$, and so on.

Comment: Also, I think there's small mistake in the solution. From the question, it seems as though $x_k\in \{0,1\}$ is possible. If $\alpha_k \neq 0$, we wouldn't get $\alpha_k \cdot f(x_k) = |\alpha_k|$ if we defined $f(0)=f(1)=0$. The function should be defined as $f(0)=0$ if $x_k\neq 0$ for any $k$. Similar for $f(1)=0$.

Comment: @zugzug completely right, thank you