# What is the intuition behind defining the function for calculating the norm like this?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Here is the link of the function I am speaking about:

[Finding the norm of an operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604987/finding-the-norm-of-an-operator/3605037#3605037)

---

And here is the function:

$$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = \alpha_k \geq 0 \\
-1 & x = \alpha_k < 0 \\
0 & x \in \{0,1\} \setminus \{\alpha_k\}_{k =1}^n
\end{cases}
$$

Here is the question:

Let $X = C[0,1]$ with $\|.\|_{\max}$ norm, let $\{ \alpha_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ be real numbers, let $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n} \subset [0,1],$ and define $$ T f = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k} f(x_{k}). $$ Prove that $T$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and find its norm.

**My questions are:**

(1) In the defined function, should not we respect the given that "$\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n} \subset [0,1]$ " How can we say that $x = \alpha_{k} \geq 0 $? is not the $\{ \alpha_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ are real numbers?

(2) How can I prove that the defined function continuous?

Comment: You are not understanding the definition of the function. What you want is a norm $1$ function $f$ so that $Tf = \sum_k \alpha_k f(x_k) $ is maximised. What does this mean? Norm $1$ means that $f$ only takes values in the unit ball of $\Bbb C$ (or $[-1,1]$ if you are looking only at real valued functions). If you want to maximise the expression, well $| \sum_k \alpha_k f(x_k)| ≤ \sum_k |\alpha_k|$ for norm one functions, so can this bound be attained, if so how? Well what you need is that at the point $x_k$ the function $f$ takes on the value $\mathrm{sign}(\alpha_k)$.

Comment: That is how you want to construct the function. You want $f(x_k)$ to be $1$ if $\alpha_k≥0$ and $-1$ if $\alpha_k<0$. What $f$ does at the other points doesn't matter, as long as its values remain in $[-1,1]$ and $f$ is continuous. Does something like this exist? (There are multiple typos in the answer you link, but it is more important to understand the idea, then you can do the calculations correctly yourself)

Comment: what about the points $\{0,1\}$ is there a problem at them ?@s.harp

Comment: @s.harp could you please point out the typos in the link I mentioned above?

Comment: I suspect it was meant for $X=C[-1,1]$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you mean that the main question has a typo? why we require $X=C[-1,1]$?

Comment: Maybe....................

Comment: The original question is fine, the third line of the definition of $f$ (the line with $f(x)=0$ if $x\in \{0,1\} \setminus \{\alpha_k\}$) is a typo.

Comment: @s.harp the author has changed the definition to $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = x_k, \alpha_k \geq 0 \\

-1 & x = x_k, \alpha_k < 0 \\

0 & x \in \{0,1\} \setminus \{x_k\}_{k =1}^n

\end{cases}$$
 Is this definition fine now? In my opinion it is correct now....am I correct?