# The correct way of writing the maximum norm in the given problem.

Tags: normed-spaces

I was trying to solve this problem:

Let $X = C[0,1]$ with $\|.\|_{\max}$ norm, let $\{ \alpha_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ be real numbers, let $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n} \subset [0,1],$ and define $$ T f = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k} f(x_{k}). $$ Prove that $T$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and find its norm.

**My question is:**

When I wrote the norm like this

$\|f\|_{\max} = \max_{\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n} \in [0,1]} |f(x_{k})|$

My professor said that this way of writing is incorrect as I am taking the norm at specific points. So, what is the correct way of writing the norm in our problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of the max norm is $\|f\|=\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |f(x)|$.

Note that $|Tf| \leq \|f\| \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha_k|$ so $\|T\| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha_k|$. To show that equality golds think of a  continuous function such that $f(x_k)$ is equal to  the sign of $\alpha_k$ for each $k$.

Comment: I was given the function in a link that I will provide in my next comment. But I do not understand many steps in this link. like for example:  In line 2 in the answer , the author said "let $f \in X$ be arbitrary with $\|f\| = 1$ .... "then in line 8 he gave us a specific function, Is $f$ arbitrary or a specific function ?

Comment: here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604987/finding-the-norm-of-an-operator/3605037#3605037

Comment: An arbitary $f$ is needed to get a bound for the norm. To show that the bound is attained it is enough to choose  a partcticular $f$ because $\|T\| \geq |Tf|$ for any function $f$ with max norm $1$. @Mathstupid

Comment: Also, I do not understand why this definition is dealing with the points $0,1$ like this, what is the problem at these 2 points ? here is the definition : $$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = \alpha_k \geq 0 \\
-1 & x = \alpha_k < 0 \\
0 & x \in \{0,1\} \setminus \{\alpha_k\}_{k =1}^n
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609758/what-is-the-intuition-behind-defining-the-function-for-calculating-the-norm-like?noredirect=1#comment7420490_3609758

Comment: Well, to construct $f$ it is necessary to specify the values at $0$ and $1$ also along with the values at the points $x_k$. So the actual definition depends on whether $0$ and $1$ are already among the points $x_k$ or not. @Mathstupid

Comment: and why the author put $f(x) = 0$ in the last case?

Comment: Good point. Any number between $0$ and $1$ would have been good enough. But remember that we just need one function $f$ with some properties. They chose the value $0$ fro definiteness. @Mathstupid

Comment: what do you mean by for definiteness?

Comment: do you mean positive definiteness? the condition that must be satisfied by the norm

Comment: They did not choose the value $0$ for any particular reason. Take it as $0.5$ or $\frac  1 {\sqrt 2}$ if you want and you will still get a complete and correct proof.

Comment: Should $X = C[-1,1]$ in the main question ? or $X = C[0,1]$ is correct . someone pointed out that this maybe a typo.