# Why is the function defined continuous?

Tags: analysis, continuity

Here is the function:

Define

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & x = x_k, \alpha_k \geq 0\\
-1 & x = x_k, \alpha_k < 0\\
0 & x \in \{0,1\} \setminus \{x_k\}_{k =1}^n
\end{cases}
$$

and linear interpolation otherwise. Then this function is continuous on $[0,1]$, it has $\Vert f \Vert = 1.$

It is defined in this link:

[Finding the norm of an operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604987/finding-the-norm-of-an-operator/3605037#3605037)

Why is the function defined continuous?

Comment: There are only a finite number of $x_k$, so it's a piecewise linear function. Does that justify it being continuous for you, or are you asking for a grinding out the details proof that piecewise linear functions are continuous?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC If you gave me the details I would be thankful for this :)

Comment: Me, I would just cite the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), and think it's sufficient, but what you consider to be a proper answer depends mostly on how powerful a tool you want to use (is topology okay?) and what level of detail you want. If you sketch out how you would approach it maybe some other folks can help you.